# How to animate multiple video layers at the same time in AVMutableComposition?

Tags: ios, video, core-animation, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

I'm writing a piece of code that generates a slide show video from multiple images and multiple videos on iOS devices. I was able to do so with a single video and multiple images, but I'm not be able to figure out how to enhance it to multiple videos.

Here is [the sample video](http://satoshi.blogs.com/veemob/IMG_1303.MOV) I was able to generate with one video and two images.

Here is the main routine, which prepares the exporter.

```
// Prepare the temporary location to store generated video
NSURL * urlAsset = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[StoryMaker tempFilePath:@"mov"]];

// Prepare composition and _exporter
AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVAssetExportSession* exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL = urlAsset;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = [self _addVideo:composition time:timeVideo];
```

Here is the _addVideo:time: method, which creates the videoLayer.

```
-(AVVideoComposition*) _addVideo:(AVMutableComposition*)composition time:(CMTime)timeVideo {
    AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComposition.renderSize = _sizeVideo;
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30); // 30fps
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,timeVideo) ofTrack:_baseVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    // Prepare the parent layer
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _sizeVideo.width, _sizeVideo.height);

    // Prepare images parent layer
    CALayer *imageParentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageParentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _sizeVideo.width, _sizeVideo.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:imageParentLayer];

    // Specify the perspecrtive view
    CATransform3D perspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
    perspective.m34 = -1.0 / imageParentLayer.frame.size.height;
    imageParentLayer.sublayerTransform = perspective;

    // Animations
    _beginTime = 1E-10;
    _endTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeVideo);

    CALayer* videoLayer = [self _addVideoLayer:imageParentLayer];
    [self _addAnimations:imageParentLayer time:timeVideo];

    videoComposition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    // Prepare the instruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    {
        instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, timeVideo);
        AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[composition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
        AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
        [layerInstruction setTransform:_baseVideoTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
        instruction.layerInstructions = @[layerInstruction];
    }
    videoComposition.instructions = @[instruction];
    return videoComposition;
}
```

_addAnimation:time: method adds image layers, and schedule the animations of all the layers including the _videoLayer.

Everything works fine so far.

I, however, can't figure out how to add the second video to this slide show.

The sample in the AVFoundation Programming Guide uses multiple video composition instructions (AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction) to combine two videos, but it simply renders them into a single CALayer object, which is specified in videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:inLayer: method (of AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool).

I want render two video tracks into two separate layers (layer1 and layer2), and animate them separately, just like I'm doing with the layers associated with images.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: No, I haven't. I think this is the limitation of AVFoundation.

Comment: Where do you actually add the image to the image layer?

Comment: can you share you code?

Comment: I have same requirement and I am stuck as at present core animation tool accepts only one video layer and I want to play videos in different layers. Did you succeed? If so please do let us all know, how did you achieve the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem too and wanted to animate multiple videos. I found that `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` can accept multiple video layers, however the catch is they are multiple instances of the same video. So my workaround was to make one large video with the 2 videos sitting next to each other, and use masks to show each video in it's own layer.

This is how the video layer would look:
[image: videos1]

And here is a rough idea of that layer being used in a mask to show each video:
[image: videos2]
[image]

Here is my code, you just need 2 example videos to make it work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myurl: URL?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


@IBAction func newMerge(_ sender: Any) {

    print("making vid")

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample_video", ofType:"mp4")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    let vid = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL as URL)

    let path2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "example2", ofType:"mp4")
    let fileURL2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path2!)

    let vid2 = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL2 as URL)

    newoverlay(video: vid, withSecondVideo: vid2)

}


func newoverlay(video firstAsset: AVURLAsset, withSecondVideo secondAsset: AVURLAsset) {


    // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    // 2 - Create two video tracks
    guard let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                          preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }
    do {
        try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: firstAsset.duration),
                                       of: firstAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                                       at: CMTime.zero)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to load first track")
        return
    }

    guard let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video,
                                                           preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else { return }
    do {
        try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: secondAsset.duration),
                                        of: secondAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                                        at: CMTime.zero)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to load second track")
        return
    }




    // Watermark Effect
    let width: CGFloat = firstTrack.naturalSize.width + secondTrack.naturalSize.width
    let height: CGFloat = CGFloat.maximum(firstTrack.naturalSize.height, secondTrack.naturalSize.height)


    //bg layer
    let bglayer = CALayer()
    bglayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    bglayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let box1 = CALayer()
    box1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: firstTrack.naturalSize.width, height: firstTrack.naturalSize.height - 1)
    box1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    box1.masksToBounds = true

    let timeInterval: CFTimeInterval = 1
    let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = 1.0
    scaleAnimation.toValue = 1.1
    scaleAnimation.autoreverses = true
    scaleAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    scaleAnimation.duration = timeInterval
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount=Float.infinity
    scaleAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
    box1.add(scaleAnimation, forKey: nil)

    let box2 = CALayer()
    box2.frame = CGRect(x: firstTrack.naturalSize.width + 100, y: 0, width: secondTrack.naturalSize.width, height: secondTrack.naturalSize.height)
    box2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    box2.masksToBounds = true

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -(height - firstTrack.naturalSize.height), width: width + 2, height: height + 2)
    videolayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let videolayer2 = CALayer()
    videolayer2.frame = CGRect(x: -firstTrack.naturalSize.width, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    videolayer2.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(bglayer)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(box1)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(box2)
    box1.addSublayer(videolayer)
    box2.addSublayer(videolayer2)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    layercomposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayers: [videolayer, videolayer2], in: parentlayer)

    // 2.1
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration))

    // 2.2 - this is where the 2 videos get combined into one large one.
    let firstInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: firstTrack)
    let move = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    firstInstruction.setTransform(move, at: CMTime.zero)

    let secondInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: secondTrack)
    let move2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: firstTrack.naturalSize.width, y: 0)
    secondInstruction.setTransform(move2, at: CMTime.zero)

    // 2.3
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstInstruction, secondInstruction]
    //let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)


    layercomposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    mainInstruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor


    //  create new file to receive data
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as NSString
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)

    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition

    // Check exist and remove old file
    FileManager.default.removeItemIfExisted(movieDestinationUrl as URL)

    assetExport?.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl as URL
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport!.status {
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed:
            print("failed")
            print(assetExport?.error ?? "unknown error")
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
            print(assetExport?.error ?? "unknown error")
        default:
            print("Movie complete")

            self.myurl = movieDestinationUrl as URL

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: movieDestinationUrl as URL)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    print("Saved")
                }
            }

            self.playVideo()

        }
    })
}



func playVideo() {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: myurl!)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
    print("playing...")
}



}


extension FileManager {
func removeItemIfExisted(_ url:URL) -> Void {
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: url.path)
        }
        catch {
            print("Failed to delete file")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your answer was very useful to me, I wish I could connect with you on LinkedIn.

Comment: Holy cow, who would've thought that adding an 's' to `postProcessingAsVideoLayer` solves all my problems

Comment: What if I want 1 of those videos to be circular and smaller than the other? Can I somehow make it scale aspect fill?